# If $G$ has only 2 non-trivial proper subgroups H, N, then H, N are cyclic subgroup of $G$.

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

> If $G$ has only 2 non-trivial proper subgroups H, N
>
> , then H, N are cyclic subgroup of $G$.

I searched essentially same problem  at

[If $G$ has only 2 proper, non-trivial subgroups then $G$ is cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378376/if-g-has-only-2-proper-non-trivial-subgroups-then-g-is-cyclic)

So, I already know the solving method of my question.

1. $G$ is cyclic.
2. subgroup of cyclic subgroup is cyclic.
3. Therefore H, N are cyclic.

$$
$$
***In this time,***

I'd like to know other method solving my question.

> i.e.
>
> Can anybody show my question, ***not through*** "$G$ is cyclic."

$$
$$

Umm, maybe this is useless question.... :-(

But I spent lots of time for solving this question.

Thank you for your attention to this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any group with at most one non-trivial proper subgroup is cyclic: any element not in the non-trivial proper subgroup (or not the identity if there is none) must generate the whole group. Neither of the subgroups $H,N$ of the question can have more than one non-trivial proper subgroup (as with the subgroup itself that would give more than two non-trivial proper subgroups of $G$), so by the above they must be cyclic.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I need.