# $G$ a finite group with two non-trivial normal subgroups. $|G| = pq$. Why is $G$ cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

How can I prove that if $G$ is a finite group , and the order of $G$ is $pq$ while $p$ and $q$ are primes, and in addition , $G$ with two normalic subgroups , so --> $G$ is cycle?
Ideas?
Hwo can i show that have just one subgroup for any divisior of pq?

Comment: what theorems do you have at your disposal?

Answer (score 2):

By Sylow theory the two subgroups are then the **only** non-trivial subgroups of $G$.

Hint: Show that the must exist an element that does not belong to either of those subgroups. What is the subgroup it generates?

Comment: Making my answer CW because I have used this idea at least twice already. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/378412/11619) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/67409/11619).

Comment: How can i do it by this way: to assume there is anothersubgroup of order p, go through "Quotient group" and reach a contradiction

Answer (score 1):

Let $P, Q$ the subgroups with order $p, q$. As @Jyrki indicated earlier these are the only nontrivial subgroups of G. Let $a \in P, b \in Q$ have orders $p, q$. Consider the element $ab$. Since $p, q$ are relatively prime $a$ is not a power of $b$ and vice versa. Then $ab$ is not in $P, Q$. Since $ab$ is an element of $G$, the order of $ab$ must divide the order of $G$. Then the order of $ab$ is in $\{1, p, q, pq\}$. As $a, b$ are in different groups they are not inverses so it is not $1$. $ab$ is not in $P$ or $Q$ so $ab$ does not have order $p$ or $q$ and therefore must have order $pq$. Then $G$ is generated by $ab$. Then $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: Can you explain it: "..therefore must have order pq"

Comment: You followed up to $ab$ is not in $P$ or $Q$?

Comment: Edited answer. Since $ab \in G$ its order must divide the order of $G$, which makes it either $1, p, q, pq$. More details in edited answer.

Comment: You can explain why these are the only nontrivial subgroups of G? and why there must be normal subgroups? it's not clear from his answer

Comment: As @Jyrki stated it's a result of the Sylow theorems. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems#Theorems It may be better to open another question/check old questions if you would like the proof of those. IIRC the proof of it is somewhat lengthy

Comment: Hwo can i get contradict if i assume that has more subgroup with order of p? (it's need be with Quotient group)

Comment: I don't think you need quotient groups or that $P, Q$ are normal for this proof.

Comment: How can i do it by this way: to assume there is another subgroup of order p, go through "Quotient group" and reach a contradiction