# If G has only two nontrivial proper subgroups,then show that G is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I did it as follows:
let order of G is n.let a,b be two non identity elements of G.If G is commutative then (ab) is a cyclic group other than (a) and (b),which is a contradiction,hence one of a and b must be of order n.so G is cyclic.If G is non commutative then G can't be cyclic.so we are done.
This question is already asked in M S E and various answers are also given,but not this.Have  I done any mistake?

Comment: Well...for one thing, how do you know $G$ is abelian?  For another, if $b=a^k$ for some $k$ then $<ab>$ needn't be different from $<a>$ or $<b>$.  (or, if $b=a^{-1}$, we might have $<ab>=e$).

Comment: got it.but if i do: let G is not cyclic.so there exists one b s.t. it can't be written as power of a. then <ab> is diffenent from them.

Comment: "If G is non commutative then G can't be cyclic.so we are done." Why are you done then???

Comment: So, maybe $G$ is not abelian.  This is not as simple as you are making it out, though there are elementary proofs.  See the responses to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378376/if-g-has-only-2-proper-non-trivial-subgroups-then-g-is-cyclic)

Comment: ok got it.if b is a inverse then there is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $O(G)=n$. Then $n$ has at most two distinct prime factors as three prime factor give three distinct elements of that order (Cauchy theorem) and hence three distinct subgroups. So $O(G)$ is either $p^k$ or $pq$ where $p,q$ are distinct primes.
Case(i): If $O(G)=p$, though $G$ is cyclic but the condition failed.
Case(ii): If $O(G)=p^2$ Since $G$ has two nontrivial subgroup, $G=H\cup K$ where $H,K$ are two distinct subgroup of order $p$. Equating number of elements we get $p^2=2p-1$ which cant be true.
Case(iii): If $O(G)=p^3$. There exist subgroup $H$ of order $p$ and a subgroup $K$ of order $p^2$ by Sylow theorem on p-groups. They are unique and $K$ must have subgroup of order $p$, so $H\leq K$. This gives number of element of $G$ is atmost $p^2$, a contradiction.
Case(iii) If $O(G)=p^k$($k\geq4$): Sylow theorems on p-group gives at least three subgroups of order $p,p^2,p^3$. Thus the condition failed. Case(iv) If $O(G)=pq$: There exist subgroup $H$ of order $p$ and a subgroup $K$ of order $q$. Those are unique and hence normal. Also $H\cap K=\{id\}$. So $G=HK$ is abelian and hence cyclic.